# Using LINQ to select a list of every item in a collection, except if it exists in another collection

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda, ienumerable

This works, but not only looks bad, but doesn't seem terribly efficient (I have not evaluated performance yet since I know there must be a better way to do this).

```
public IEnumerable<Observation> AvailableObservations
{
    get 
    {
        foreach (var observation in db.Observations)
        {
            if (Observations.Any(x => x.Id == observation.Id))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                yield return observation;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially, I want everything in the list `db.Observations`
(which pulled from db via EF6) and remove all the entries currently selected in `this.Observations`, which is an `ICollection<Observations>`

I've tried using .Except(this.Observations) but get an error that I believe might be related to using except with an ICollection on an entity that is an IEnumerable.

Anything that will remove the `foreach` loop would be a good start.

Comment: It would be helpful to tell us the *exact* error message that you're currently getting.

Comment: What is the actual error?  `Any` should work just fine in an `ICollection<T>`.

Comment: When I try to use .Except(this.Observations), I get the following error:

Additional information: Unable to create a constant value of type 'MultiSelectExample.Models.Observation'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well your loop is equivalent to:

```
return db.Observations.Where(o => !Observations.Any(oo => oo.Id == o.Id));
```

but that's no more efficient that what you have.

A more efficient method would be to create a HashSet of IDs and filter off of that:

```
HashSet<int> ids = new HashSet<int>(Observations.Select(o => o.Id));
return db.Observations.Where(o => !ids.Contains(o.Id));
```

That way you're only traversing the main list once in order to create a `HashSet` that can be searched in O(1) time.

Comment: I went with the HashSet option.  Thanks much for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can do two optimizations here:

1. Limit the number of observations you fetch from the database
2. Make the lookup of the selected observation IDs quicker

The current implementation has a `O(N * M)` complexity, where `N` is the number of items in `db.Observations` and `M` is the number of items in `this.Observations`.

What would help performance would be to first create a `HashSet` of the IDs in `this.Observations`:

```
var observationIds = new HashSet<int>(this.Observations.Select(x => x.Id));
```

This will allow you to do quick lookups on the IDs.

Combine this with a where clause (using LINQ's `Where()`) to get an efficient query:

```
public IEnumerable<Observation> AvailableObservations
{
    get 
    {
        var observationIds = new HashSet<int>(this.Observations.Select(x => x.Id));
        return db.Observations.Where(x => !observationIds.Contains(x.Id));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the analysis & opportunities.  I can't limit the # of Observations returned, as the user must be able to select any within their scope to associate with an Action entity.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're aware that by calling `Where` on an `IDbSet<T>` will actually limit the # of observations returned? It will literally add `NOT IN (<list of ids>)` to the generated SQL query. As opposed to your example where your loop over the whole set.